# Photodiode Amplifier Circuit Design

Tags: circuit-design, photodiode, transimpedance

I'm working with a mid-infrared (~4um) photodiode model Lms43PD-03-CG ([Datasheet](http://www.eoc-inc.com/LED%20Microsensor/lms43pd-03-cg.pdf)) and a matching LED ([Datasheet](http://lmsnt.com/datasheets/Standard%20chip/Lms43LED-CG/Lms43LED-CG_TO18_rev240317.pdf)). (I can't switch from this photodiode/LED pair) I'm trying to make a functioning photodiode amplifier but have not been able to get the photodiode to respond.

I've tried a basic photodiode amplifier but no feedback resistor value would work. I tried adding a capacitor to stabilize the trans-impedance amplifier but no values appeared to work. I tried biasing the positive input of the op amp to not ride the rails, and still nothing.

I've recently started experimenting with using photoconductive mode (to increase the power source of the photodiode), but don't know/can't find much information about designing a photoconductive photodiode amplifier. I even tried using Analog's design tool but photodiode's specifications our outside of their photodiode parameters.

This is the design that I'm looking to design around with the photodiode being reverse biased. I am connecting the photodiode amplifier to a lock-in amplifier once I get the photodiode responding to light and creating a voltage response. I am checking the output signals with an oscilloscope.

Some other important information:

The op-amp I am using is the MCP6002. The desired frequency is at most 10kHz.

[image: Photodiode Amplifier]

Here are my questions:

1. In the photodiode datasheet, there is a reverse voltage of 0.1V. Is this the same as the breakdown voltage, the max voltage that photodiodes may safely receive?
2. Would this circuit require a capacitor? If so, what equations should I use to determine this capacitor value? I've tried several such as TI's photodiode design guide to no avail.
3. What should I be cautious about designing this photodiode amplifier? I'll make sure to bias the positive input to avoid the rails.
4. What else could be causing this circuit to not respond? No matter how much I shine a MIR LED to the photodiode from a short distance, it doesn't respond.

Comment: What supply voltages have you tried?

Comment: You say you can't change devices, but at the same time your photodiode has a big hole in its response spectrum right at the peak of your LEDs output spectrum. You might just have a bad set of requirements here.

Comment: What is your purpose in this circuit? To get Logic output? If you want to get logic, than i would ask you what is the resistor value do you use or did you try other values suitable for your design? Transimpedence amplifiers usually require big feedback resistance values.

Comment: I've tried positive and negative voltages of 5V, 3.3V, 1V, and nothing else. Also the purpose of the circuit is a CO2 sensor. I'll probably use an Arduino to pick up the signal and process it. So @ThePhoton, if CO2 is absorbed at 2.7, 4.3, and 15um, 2.7um would be better sensitivity for the photodiode? I didn't realize that the hole in the spectral response was literally what my LED was outputting. Would this overlap in peaks really not allow me to see any signal change?

For the resistor values I used (Vsupply - Vled)/Imaxcurrent and got ~30ohms

Comment: @user154025 Have you made sure you do these?:● check your connection circuit before turning on the PD;
● mind the PD polarity: PD anode is marked with a RED dot;
● do not connect the PD to the multimeter;
● do not touch the glass covering and do not apply any force to it;
● observe the allowable operating temperature range, exceeding this eange may cause irreparable damage of the glass cover

Comment: Yes, the photodiode is quite expensive and I treat it appropriately. Atleast, I try to. @laptop2d

Comment: @user, It's not clear if the drop in the response at the CO2 absorbtion band is inherent to the device, or if they just measured through a long air column and didn't bother to correct for it. Probably worth asking the vendor.

Comment: When using +/-5V supplies on your op-amp, what's the DC output voltage when the sensor is dark?  (And what feedback resistor you value do you think you need?)

Comment: @JohnD, maximum power supply for this op-amp is 6 V, 7 V is absolute maximum. OP, if you tried +/- 5 V supplies, you may have killed your op-amp.

Comment: @ThePhoton good catch, I read his comment above as having tried +/-5V supplies already, so I didn't check the datasheet.  So same question for +/-2.5V supplies assuming the op-amp hasn't been damaged.  Also, is the anode of the diode connected to ground or a negative bias voltage? The dark current on the photodiode is fairly high so it might be railing the output depending on Rf.

Comment: Aha bad choice of +/- 5 volts. Read the DS.

Comment: I think I mistook your question, I thought you meant supply voltages for the photodiode. I've only been inputting a 5V power supply to the MCP6002, I can assure you that blowing the op amp is not the issue. But on that topic, is 5V enough? @JohnD, above I mentioned I thought I needed a ~32ohm feedback resistor, is this correct? Also, I used a negative bias voltage which is what I meant with the 5, 3.3, and 1 V supplied.

Comment: @user154025 OK, got it.  Your single supply of 5V for the op-amp should be OK.  What's the DC value at the output with the sensor in the dark? (And no more than 0.1V reverse bias on the diode.)

Comment: @user154025 Also, with respect to: "I've tried positive and negative voltages of 5V, 3.3V, 1V, and nothing else." you said you were referring to "supply voltages for the photodiode".  Are you implying that you forward biased the diode with a +5V supply on the anode in the circuit shown?

Comment: @JohnD That's part of my question, for the reverse bias do you mean supplying the photodiode with 0.1V? Does this make the reverse voltage the equivalent of the breakdown voltage? As for me trying different values, I followed the schematic for negative voltages and flipped the photodiode for positive voltages. Is that an issue?

Comment: @ThePhoton, I contacted the vendor and was told that the spectral response is normal. There is a loss of signal when CO2 is added to the line of sight of the photodiode. Could this be why I'm not seeing a change by shining the LED? I could test adding a vial of CO2 

(Also sorry if double comments are against the rules)

Comment: I'm not sure if that clarifies if the effect is internal the device, or caused by CO2 in the path from the source to the photodiode (which is presumably what you're trying to measure).

Comment: I believe that the effect caused by the CO2 is intentional and will allow me to measure CO2 levels @ThePhoton, my issue is with the transimpeadance amplifier design for the photodiode

Comment: @user154025 Yes, the anode of the diode should be biased to a negative voltage.  The data sheet specs give the dark current for a negative 0.1V bias (the cathode will be at virtual ground, so 0V).  So starting there you should see the output at less than 200mV DC with no light on the diode.